# javascript isNaN() function not working?

Tags: javascript

I have a function to test if a prompt input is a number, like so:

```
function myFunction() 
{
    var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "");

    if (person != null) 
    {
        if(isNaN(person))
        {
            document.write("hello " + person + "<br><br>");
        }
        else
            document.write("You gave me a number");

    }
    else
    {
        document.write("You didn't answer.<br><br>");
    }
}
```

but every time I enter a number it keeps outputting hello + the number. I've been googling this function for quite some time and it doesn't make sense to me, it seems like it should work. Why is person returning true?

Comment: Try replacing all your `document.write` calls with `console.log` and see what happens. Then read up on how [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) works.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. What browser are you using?

Comment: Just because it isn't `NaN` or `null` doesn't mean it's an integer...

Comment: you're right @GeorgeSimms, this code doesn't produce an error. it wasn't my javascript code. I messed up the name of the javascript file in my html code >.< oops...... I guess the best answer would go to you? I'm not sure if I should close this thread or what..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is the correct way of using the `isNaN` method. However for anyone else reading this post I have seen a strange anomaly where the documented usage of `iNaN` hasn't worked properly and I got around the problem by combining the `parseInt` method with the `isNaN` method. According to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) the `isNan('123')` should return false and `isNan('g12')` should return true, but I've seen scenarios where this isn't the case.
If you're having trouble getting the documented methods to work try this code below:

```
var unitsToAdd = parseInt($('#unitsToAdd').val());
if(isNaN(unitsToAdd)) {
    alert('not a number');
    $('#unitsToAdd').val('1');
    returnVal = false;
}
```

Alternatively you can try this method which is well tested.

```
function isNumber(searchValue) {
    var found = searchValue.search(/^(\d*\.?\d*)$/);
    //Change to ^(\d*\.?\d+)$ if you don't want the number to end with a . such as 2.
    //Currently validates .2, 0.2, 2.0 and 2.
    if(found > -1) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[NaN is a special value in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN). What `isNaN` does is check to see if the value passed is equal* to this special value. If you want to check if something is, say, not a stream of numbers, you can use a regular expression:

```
if (!/^\d+(\.\d+)?/.exec(person)) {
```

Or parse the value as a number and see if it converts back to the same string:

```
var n = parseFloat(person);
if (n.toString() !== person) {
```

*There's a reason that we don't use `===` but it's outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: You can also just as easy check for `NaN` using `if(x != x) { ... }` which only holds true for `NaN`...

Answer (score 4):

The isNaN function checks if a value is NaN. NaN is a value that occurs when making operations that require numbers with non-numbers. Please see the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).
However the function **does not** check if the value is of type number. Too check if a value is of type number use the `typeof` operator

```
typeof person === 'number'
```